# Getting Error from Generic Class and Comparator

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have encountered some issues while coding my generic class with a comparator. I have a class called PQ that takes in a Comparator.
This is my class PQ.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
  
class PQ<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private final ArrayList<T> queue;

    PQ(Comparator<T> cmp){
        this.queue = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    PQ(ArrayList<T> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
```

So the error happens when the question requires my code to take in

```
Comparator<Object> c = (x, y) -> x.hashCode() - y.hashCode()
```

```
pq = new PQ<String>(c)
```

This error pops up.

```
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   variable pq
|  pq = new PQ<String>(c)
|  ^^
|  Error:
|  no suitable constructor found for PQ(java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object>)
|      constructor PQ.PQ(java.util.Comparator<java.lang.String>) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.Comparator<java.lang.String>)
|      constructor PQ.PQ(ImList<java.lang.String>) is not applicable
|        (argument mismatch; java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to ImList<java.lang.String>)
|  pq = new PQ<String>(c)
|       ^---------------^
```

Would really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: `argument mismatch; java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.Comparator<java.lang.String>`

Comment: Please read through [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pq = new PQ<String>(c) // T is String
```

In this way, you specified the generic parameters T is String, so those two constructors will accept `Comparator<String>` or `ImList<String>`.You just give the wrong parameter `Comparator<Object>`.

```
pq = new PQ<Object>(c) // T is Object, any subclass can be accept
```

You can change to this get it worked.